# Как посчитать CRC в C#?

Tags: c#

Как посчитать CRC в C#?

Comment: [Быстрая и грязная реализация](http://www.sanity-free.org/12/crc32_implementation_in_csharp.html) [Еще одна](http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net) [Для потоков](http://netobf.com/Examples_CRC32)

Comment: Какую CRC? Много их разных

Comment: CRC32 надо

Answer (score 5):

Взять [исходник на C](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRC#CRC-32) и перенести на C#

```
byte[] source = {0, 1, 2};

UInt32[] crc_table = new UInt32[256];
UInt32 crc;

for (UInt32 i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    crc = i;
    for (UInt32 j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        crc = (crc & 1) != 0 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xEDB88320 : crc >> 1;

    crc_table[i] = crc;
};

crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;

foreach (byte s in source) {
    crc = crc_table[(crc ^ s) & 0xFF] ^ (crc >> 8);
}

crc ^= 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

P.S. На ошибки не проверял.

Comment: для чего нужно crc_table?

Answer (score 3):

Как подсчитать CRC32 (Cyclic Redundancy Checksum) для строки в .NET?

Реализация на C# CRC32 Framework 2

> Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread threadCRC32 = new Thread(CRC32);
        threadCRC32.Start();

        bool exit = false;
        while (!exit)
        {
            var vExit = Console.ReadLine() == "exit" ? exit = true : exit = false;
        }
    }
    static void CRC32()
    {
        Crc32 crc32 = new Crc32();
        String hash = String.Empty;
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(Application.ExecutablePath))
        {
            foreach (byte b in crc32.ComputeHash(fs))
            {
                hash += b.ToString("x2").ToLower();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("this Application CRC-32 is {0}", hash);
        }
    }
}
```

> CRC32.cs

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

public class Crc32 : HashAlgorithm
{
    public const UInt32 DefaultPolynomial = 0xedb88320;
    public const UInt32 DefaultSeed = 0xffffffff;

    private UInt32 hash;
    private UInt32 seed;
    private UInt32[] table;
    private static UInt32[] defaultTable;

    public Crc32()
    {
        table = InitializeTable(DefaultPolynomial);
        seed = DefaultSeed;
        Initialize();
    }

    public Crc32(UInt32 polynomial, UInt32 seed)
    {
        table = InitializeTable(polynomial);
        this.seed = seed;
        Initialize();
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        hash = seed;
    }

    protected override void HashCore(byte[] buffer, int start, int length)
    {
        hash = CalculateHash(table, hash, buffer, start, length);
    }

    protected override byte[] HashFinal()
    {
        byte[] hashBuffer = UInt32ToBigEndianBytes(~hash);
        this.HashValue = hashBuffer;
        return hashBuffer;
    }

    public override int HashSize
    {
        get { return 32; }
    }

    public static UInt32 Compute(byte[] buffer)
    {
        return ~CalculateHash(InitializeTable(DefaultPolynomial), DefaultSeed, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    public static UInt32 Compute(UInt32 seed, byte[] buffer)
    {
        return ~CalculateHash(InitializeTable(DefaultPolynomial), seed, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    public static UInt32 Compute(UInt32 polynomial, UInt32 seed, byte[] buffer)
    {
        return ~CalculateHash(InitializeTable(polynomial), seed, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    private static UInt32[] InitializeTable(UInt32 polynomial)
    {
        if (polynomial == DefaultPolynomial && defaultTable != null)
            return defaultTable;

        UInt32[] createTable = new UInt32[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        {
            UInt32 entry = (UInt32)i;
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                if ((entry & 1) == 1)
                    entry = (entry >> 1) ^ polynomial;
                else
                    entry = entry >> 1;
            createTable[i] = entry;
        }

        if (polynomial == DefaultPolynomial)
            defaultTable = createTable;

        return createTable;
    }

    private static UInt32 CalculateHash(UInt32[] table, UInt32 seed, byte[] buffer, int start, int size)
    {
        UInt32 crc = seed;
        for (int i = start; i < size; i++)
            unchecked
            {
                crc = (crc >> 8) ^ table[buffer[i] ^ crc & 0xff];
            }
        return crc;
    }

    private byte[] UInt32ToBigEndianBytes(UInt32 x)
    {
        return new byte[] {
            (byte)((x >> 24) & 0xff),
            (byte)((x >> 16) & 0xff),
            (byte)((x >> 8) & 0xff),
            (byte)(x & 0xff)
        };
    }

    public string Get(string FilePath)
    {
        Crc32 crc32 = new Crc32();
        String hash = String.Empty;

        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Open))
            foreach (byte b in crc32.ComputeHash(fs)) hash += b.ToString("x2").ToLower();

        return hash;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Быстрые реализации CRC:

**CRC8:**

```
public static class Crc8
{
    private static readonly byte[] Table = new byte[256];
    private const byte Poly = 0xd5;

    public static byte ComputeChecksum(params byte[] bytes)
    {
        byte crc = 0;
        if (bytes is {Length: > 0}) crc = bytes.Aggregate(crc, (current, b) => Table[current ^ b]);
        return crc;
    }

    static Crc8()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        {
            var temp = i;
            for (var j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
                if ((temp & 0x80) != 0)
                    temp = (temp << 1) ^ Poly;
                else
                    temp <<= 1;
            Table[i] = (byte) temp;
        }
    }
}
```

**CRC16 с модификацией на CCiTT + Kermit:**

```
public class Crc16
{
    public enum Crc16Mode : ushort
    {
        Standard = 0xA001,
        CcittKermit = 0x8408
    }

    private readonly ushort[] _table = new ushort[256];

    private ushort ComputeChecksum(params byte[] bytes)
    {
        return bytes.Aggregate<byte, ushort>(0, (current, t) => (ushort) ((current >> 8) ^ _table[(byte) (current ^ t)]));
    }

    public byte[] ComputeChecksumBytes(params byte[] bytes)
    {
        var crc = ComputeChecksum(bytes);
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(crc);
    }

    public Crc16(Crc16Mode mode)
    {
        var polynomial = (ushort) mode;
        for (ushort i = 0; i < _table.Length; ++i)
        {
            ushort value = 0;
            var temp = i;
            for (byte j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            {
                if (((value ^ temp) & 0x0001) != 0)
                    value = (ushort) ((value >> 1) ^ polynomial);
                else
                    value >>= 1;
                temp >>= 1;
            }

            _table[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**CRC16 + CCiTT:**

```
public class Crc16Ccitt
{
    public enum InitialCrcValue
    {
        Zeros,
        NonZero1 = 0xffff,
        NonZero2 = 0x1D0F
    }

    private const ushort Poly = 4129;
    private readonly ushort[] _table = new ushort[256];
    private readonly ushort _initialValue;

    private ushort ComputeChecksum(IEnumerable<byte> bytes)
    {
        return bytes.Aggregate(_initialValue, (current, t) => (ushort) ((current << 8) ^ _table[(current >> 8) ^ (0xff & t)]));
    }

    public byte[] ComputeChecksumBytes(IEnumerable<byte> bytes)
    {
        var crc = ComputeChecksum(bytes);
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(crc);
    }

    public Crc16Ccitt(InitialCrcValue initialValue)
    {
        _initialValue = (ushort) initialValue;
        for (var i = 0; i < _table.Length; ++i)
        {
            ushort temp = 0;
            var a = (ushort) (i << 8);
            for (var j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            {
                if (((temp ^ a) & 0x8000) != 0)
                    temp = (ushort) ((temp << 1) ^ Poly);
                else
                    temp <<= 1;
                a <<= 1;
            }

            _table[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

**CRC32:**

```
public class Crc32
{
    private readonly uint[] _table;
    private const uint Poly = 0xedb88320;

    private uint ComputeChecksum(IEnumerable<byte> bytes)
    {
        var crc = 0xffffffff;
        foreach (var t in bytes)
        {
            var index = (byte) ((crc & 0xff) ^ t);
            crc = (crc >> 8) ^ _table[index];
        }

        return ~crc;
    }

    public IEnumerable<byte> ComputeChecksumBytes(IEnumerable<byte> bytes)
    {
        return BitConverter.GetBytes(ComputeChecksum(bytes));
    }

    public Crc32()
    {
        _table = new uint[256];
        for (uint i = 0; i < _table.Length; ++i)
        {
            var temp = i;
            for (var j = 8; j > 0; --j)
                if ((temp & 1) == 1)
                    temp = (temp >> 1) ^ Poly;
                else
                    temp >>= 1;
            _table[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

**CRC32 из кода на C выше:**

```
byte[] GetCRC32(IEnumerable<byte> bytes)
{
    var crcTable = new uint[256];
    uint crc;

    for (uint i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        crc = i;
        for (uint j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            crc = (crc & 1) != 0 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xEDB88320 : crc >> 1;

        crcTable[i] = crc;
    }

    crc = bytes.Aggregate(0xFFFFFFFF, (current, s) => crcTable[(current ^ s) & 0xFF] ^ (current >> 8));

    crc ^= 0xFFFFFFFF;
    return BitConverter.GetBytes(crc);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] // в частности, можно изложить, чем ваше предложение отличается от предыдущих.